# how to use specific font in specific text

Tags: fonts

I've used `\setmainfont{industry-blackitalic}` (after `\usepackage{fontspec}` and all my text are show in `industry-blackitalic` fonts. But I would use another font (industry-Lightitalic) for some block of text. I need to define a function that enclose the way to use this font in some piece of text, so I need to create a \newcommand command, that will set this. Can someone show me how to set it and how to let it work in specific part of text?

Thank you

Renato

Comment: All text in boldface italic? That's a peculiar choice.

Comment: in fact...I would use Lightitalic for text and Bold for dotted title...

Comment: So why state black italic for the main font?

Comment: @egreg: because first of all I need the industrial font for what I look for, first I’ve reached the industry-blackitalic, the I’ve seen that there also exists industry-Light italic and decide to used this last for the normal text and blackitaly for title. Som I’m wondering how can I set both option. I’ve read that I’ve to use \newcommand… but don’t know how...

Answer (score 2):

I'd say that typesetting the whole document in boldface italic is a peculiar choice.

Anyway, define a font face for the blocks you need to be light. I replaced font names as I don't have your fonts.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{texgyreadventor-bolditalic.otf}
\newfontface{\lightfont}{texgyreadventor-italic.otf}

\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textlight}{\lightfont}

\begin{document}

This is all in bold italic \textlight{except for this part} which is not.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot egreg...finaly I've found the right way to let it works!